# borrowed value does not live long enough reference in a struct

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and stumbled upon a problem that I cannot wrap my head around. I have a struct Customer that contains a vector of account references. The compiler suggested I should use the lifetime specifier 'a which as far as I understand means, that the accounts cannot be destroyed before the customer.

```rust
pub struct Account {
    pub balance: f32,
}

pub struct Customer<'a> {
    accounts: Vec<&'a mut Account>,
}
```

Now I want to implement a function that creates a new account for my customer, I assumed it could work something like this:

```rust
impl<'a> Customer<'a> {
    pub fn create_account(&mut self, balance: f32) {
        let mut account = Account{balance};
        self.accounts.push(&mut account);
    }
}
```

However I get an error:

```
error[E0597]: `account` does not live long enough
  --> src\banking\mod.rs:16:28
   |
8  | impl<'a> Customer<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
16 |         self.accounts.push(&mut account);
   |         -------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |         |                  |
   |         |                  borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `account` is borrowed for `'a`
17 |     }
   |     - `account` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I assume the reason is that the account variable gets destroyed at the end of the `create_account` function. However, how can I create a new account and assign it to the customer?

Answer (score 3):

Your customers currently *mutably borrow* their accounts. Someone has to own that data. Since there's no other structures in the code that I can see, I assume you meant to have the customers own the data. If so, just get rid of the `&mut`.

```
pub struct Customer {
  accounts: Vec<Account>,
}

...

impl<'a> Customer<'a> {
  pub fn create_account(&mut self, balance: f32) {
    let account = Account { balance };
    self.accounts.push(account);
  }
}
```

As a bonus point, `Customer` no longer has lifetime arguments, it simply exists independently.

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly identifying the cause of the compiler error. For how to fix it, you need to consider your design. Because your `Customer` type has a vector of *references* to `Account`s, structurally you are implying that the accounts are owned by something else. For example, you could have a `Bank` type that actually stores and owns the `Accounts`, and then the `Customer` can have a reference. Alternatively, you could change your `Customer` type to own the `Account`s, rather than references to `Account`s.